# mod rewrite works fine apart from for missing directory index files

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I have a legacy web site hosted on Apache.
It has a number of web pages sitting in the public web root and its subfolders.

For example's sake, lets say these are the **only** files and folders in  my web root:

```
publicDocs/
directorywith_no_defaultfile/
    some-legacy-flat-page.htm
.htaccess
index.php
some-legacy-flat-page.htm
```

I would like to start using Zend MVC for *some* of the newer pages.

I have got a .htaccess mod rewrite rule working so that any request for a non-existent file is sent to be handled by the MVC bootstrap file (/index.php).

With my current set-up, the following types of requests are successfully routed to '/index.php', the MVC bootstrap:

- /index.php
- /blah
- /directorywith_no_defaultfile/bloo

The following types of request are successfully served by old legacy (flat) pages

- /some-legacy-flat-page.htm
- /directorywith_no_defaultfile/some-legacy-flat-page.htm

But, when I request a non-existent file that is a directory like these:

- /directorywith_no_defaultfile

or

- /directorywith_no_defaultfile/

instead of routing these to the MVC bootsrap, I get an error:

```
Forbidden    
You don't have permission to access /directorywith_no_defaultfile/ on this server.    
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I suspect this may have something to do with the way Apache handles default files.

Currently, the only way to solve it is to:

- delete that directory (which is not possible while it holds flat legacy pages), or
- put an index.htm file in there which contains a script that include()'s the bootstrap file

Do you know which Apache directives could be causing this 'Forbidden' error?

Are the any directives i can use in .htaccess to tell Apache to 'chill out' about missing default files in directories and just leave it to the mod-rewrite to worry about?

Comment: Can you add the relevant bits of your .htaccess file to the question?

Comment: I was hoping I would not get asked that :o) - The real .htaccess file is constantly changing as I hack away and experiment  But, yes. I will make a start on trying to piece together an example that works as a kind of 'proof of concept'. Was mainly wondering if anyone had experienced this before could say "aaah! I had this issue the basic principal is to ensure xyz to avoid it"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for the DirectoryIndex directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_dir.html) includes the following:

```
Note that the documents do not need to be relative to the directory;

DirectoryIndex index.html index.txt /cgi-bin/index.pl

would cause the CGI script /cgi-bin/index.pl to be executed if neither
index.html or index.txt existed in a directory.
```

So, adding the following line in the appropriate places should do it:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php /index.php
```

Tweak this to include support for whatever types of index files you want to be handled normally.  As long as "/index.php" is the last one, it should do what you want.

Comment: yep. that solves it thanks. (It limits it to one 'mod-rewritten default bootstrap for directories with no default file' per .htaccess - but i can live with that.)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I generally setup my mod_rewrite script in the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-name.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
</IfModule>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: yes, always handy to see how others do it.